# Is this a correct way to show that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\sqrt k+k(-1)^k}$ converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

Show that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\sqrt k+k(-1)^k}$ converges or diverges. My attempt is ot first rewrite and see if the sequence is convergent according to the Leibniz test:

$\frac {1}{\sqrt k+k(-1)^k}= \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k} \frac{1}{\sqrt k + (-1)^k} \le\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k} \frac{1}{\sqrt k -1}$

Now see if it holds that:

- $a_{k+1} \le a_k$
- $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_k = 0$

The first criterion holds because the denominator is an increasing functions and thus an increasing sequence:
$f(x) = x-\sqrt x \implies f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt x} \ge 0  \forall x>2$

The second criterion also holds because: $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt k} \frac{1}{\sqrt k-1} \rightarrow 0 * 0=0 $. So according to the Leibniz test the sum converges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that $a_k=\frac1{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^kk}$ is less than $b_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}(\sqrt{k}-1)}$.  But each of these sequences is alternating in sign.  And even if $\sum_{k=2}^\infty b_k$ converges, the dominance of $b_k$ over $a_k$ does not guarantee the convergence of $\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k$.

However, we can proceed as follows.  Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^kk}&=\frac{\sqrt{k}-(-1)^kk}{k(1-k)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(1-k)}-\frac{(-1)^k}{1-k}
\end{align}$$

Hence, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^K \frac1{\sqrt{k}+(-1)^kk}&=\sum_{k=2}^K \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(1-k)}-\sum_{k=2}^K\frac{(-1)^k}{1-k}\tag1
\end{align}$$

The first sum on the right-hand side of $(1)$ converges as $K\to \infty$ by comparison to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^{3/2}}$ and the second sum converges as guaranteed by Leibniz's Test.

Comment: Mark, is it possible to look at $\frac{1}{k(-1)^{k}}$ against a variant of the alternating harmonic series. The regular one is $1, -1/2, 1/3$, but if one shifts the signs down this results in a smaller convergent series, and at even $k$ the terms are the same as $\frac{1}{k(-1)^{k}}$ and at odd $k$ the terms of $\frac{1}{k(-1)^{k}}$ of this variant of the harmonic series  will match as well.

Comment: @derekluna I'm not sure as to the question.  $\frac1{(-1)^k}=(-1)^k$.